# webrtc datachannel onopen is not fired

Tags: webrtc

My friends

I'm trying to do some test of webRTC. I start from no signal server, I copy/paste offer and answer by hand.

my process is:

setup events onicecandidate, datachannel.onopen, onmessage..etc

with pc1.onicecandidate I set pc1.addIceCandidate(event.candidate); so does pc2, am I wrong?

then create session:

pc1 createOffer and set local description

pc2 set the offer(generated by pc1 in above step) as remote description, then generate answer

pc1 set Remote Description to the answer(generated by pc2 in above step)

datachannel.onopen is not fired, do you know why? am I missing any step?

thanks very much for your help!

~Rosone

---

I'm using Chrome 28. windows 2003 32bit.

Comment: It would be helpful for others to understand your problem if you can specify what browsers/servers/environment/etc. you are using.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 28. windows 2003 32bit.

Comment: Seems this is the answer, but I have to create a server for signal to test, http://vip24.ezday.co.kr/docs/rtc-datachannel-for-beginners.html, PC1 add pc2's candidate, pc2 add pc1's candidate, they need exchange their candidate I think.

Comment: you should renegotiate the connection.

Comment: renegotiate the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work by using a socket server signaling.

pc2 should add pc1's candidate

and pc1 should add pc2's candidate.

vip24.ezday.co.kr/docs/rtc-datachannel-for-beginners.html  this really a good help.

the peers will make many candidate, and it should added to another peer after it generate one candidate, so candidate is fowarded to another peer by signaling server

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the hassle of setting up your own signaling server, you can use [Pusher](http://pusher.com) to handle that for you. It use websockets at its core which is a very good option these day since most of the [browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/websockets). Plus, it has fallback mechanisms just in case.

Here's a [webRTC signaling](http://pusher.com/tutorials/webrtc_chat) tutorial if you are interested in learning more.

http://pusher.com/tutorials/webrtc_chat

disclaimer: I work at Pusher.